# How to properly implement pagination in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, pagination

I am new to React.js. Pagination does not work when user clicks "next" `button`. I am not able to understand the reason.

I want screen to go to the next page and display new set of items when the user clicks on "next". Current behaviour: the same set of items get displayed in list view even after clicking "next".

ListViewPagination.tsx

```
import { Button, Space } from 'antd'
import { LeftOutlined, RightOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons'
import React from 'react'
import { RouteAlertsWithPagination } from '../interfaces/IRouteAlert'

const ListViewPagination = ({
  next,
  previous,
  onNext,
  onPrevious,
}: {
  onNext: () => void
  onPrevious: () => void
  next: RouteAlertsWithPagination['next']
  previous: RouteAlertsWithPagination['previous']
}): JSX.Element => {
  const handleNextAlertList = () => {
    onNext()
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }

  const handlePreviousAlertList = () => {
    onPrevious()
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }

  return (
    <Space style={{ float: 'right', marginRight: '2em', marginTop: '0.8em' }}>
      <Button
        onClick={handlePreviousAlertList}
        disabled={!previous}
        type="link"
      >
        <LeftOutlined />
        Previous
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={handleNextAlertList} disabled={!next} type="link">
        Next
        <RightOutlined />
      </Button>
    </Space>
  )
}

export default ListViewPagination
```

ListViewTable.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

import ListViewPagination from './ListViewPagination'
import ListViewTableData from './ListViewTableData'
import QuickFilterForm from './ListViewQuickFilter'
import getActiveComponent from '../helpers/getActiveComponent'
import useAlertsList from '../hooks/useAlertsList'

const ListViewTable = () => {
  const activeComponent = getActiveComponent()

  const product = activeComponent === 'messaging' ? 'message' : 'voice'

  const { alertsList, getNextPage, getPreviousPage } = useAlertsList(product)

  return (
    <>
      <QuickFilterForm />
      <ListViewTableData />
      <ListViewPagination
        next={alertsList?.next}
        previous={alertsList?.previous}
        onNext={getNextPage}
        onPrevious={getPreviousPage}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default ListViewTable
```

Code to get new page

```
const getNextPage = () => {
    const nextMessagePagePath = alertsList?.next?.split('?')[1]

    if (!nextMessagePagePath) return
    const params = new URLSearchParams(nextMessagePagePath)
    const PageToken = params.get('PageToken')
    setListViewFilters({ ...{}, ...listViewFilters, PageToken })
  }
```